# Top.gg Cooldown

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Cooldown for a discord.js bot command but it changes for those who voted for the bot on top.gg for example anyone can use the command with Cooldown 10s but if the user voted for the bot on top.gg the Cooldown will be 5s

I tried using `discord-command-cooldown` npm package to make the cooldown but I can't make the cooldown time change when the user vote for the bot
Here's my code

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.substring(0, 2) === "B!") {
    const prompt = message.content.substring(2);
    const botId = client.user.id;
    const uId = message.author.id; 
    const url = `https://top.gg/api/bots/${botId}/check?userId=${uId}`; // api endpoint
    const ask2ommandCooldown = new CommandCooldown('ask2', ms('10s'));
    const userCooldowned = await ask2ommandCooldown.getUser(message.author.id);
    fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "top.gg bot token" }})
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((json) => {
    var isVoted = JSON.parse(json).voted;

    if (userCooldowned) {
      const timeLeft = msToMinutes(userCooldowned.msLeft, false); // False for excluding '0' characters for each number < 10
      if (isVoted === 0) {
        return message.channel.send(`**You need to wait 10s before using the ask command again**`);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`**You need to wait 5s before using the ask command again**`);
      }
    } else {     
      // The command   
      if (isVoted === 0) {
        await ask2ommandCooldown.addUser(message.author.id);  
      } else {            
        await ask2ommandCooldown.addUser(message.author.id);              
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code which reorders your current command and checks if the user has voted for your bot and then determine the command cooldown.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.substring(0, 2) === "B!") {
    const prompt = message.content.substring(2);
    const botId = client.user.id;
    const uId = message.author.id; 
    const url = `https://top.gg/api/bots/${botId}/check?userId=${uId}`; // api endpoint
    fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "top.gg bot token" }})
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((json) => {
    var isVoted = JSON.parse(json).voted;
    // CHANGED LINE
    const ask2ommandCooldown = new CommandCooldown('ask2', isVoted ? ms('5s') : ms('10s'));
    const userCooldowned = await ask2ommandCooldown.getUser(message.author.id);

    if (userCooldowned) {
      const timeLeft = msToMinutes(userCooldowned.msLeft, false); // False for excluding '0' characters for each number < 10
      if (isVoted === 0) {
        return message.channel.send(`**You need to wait 10s before using the ask command again**`);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`**You need to wait 5s before using the ask command again**`);
      }
    } else {     
      // The command   
      if (isVoted === 0) {
        await ask2ommandCooldown.addUser(message.author.id);  
      } else {            
        await ask2ommandCooldown.addUser(message.author.id);              
      }
    }
  }
);
```